# Is this the Tucker-Gergonne-Nagel cubic ? or some other one

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, curves, cubics

$M$ is the intersection of 3 cevians in the triangle $ABC$.

$$
AB_1=x,~CA_1=y,~BC_1=z.
$$

[image]

it can be easily proven that for both *[Nagel](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NagelPoint.html)* point and *[Gergonne](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GergonnePoint.html)* point the following equation is true:

$$
S=\frac{xyz}{r}.
$$

Where $S$ is the area of the triangle $ABC$ and $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circle.

I wonder what other triangle centers might have the same property? Does it somehow stem from the fact that *Nagel* point is the isotomic conjugate of the *Gergonne* point? (so there might be only two in existence)   What is the locus of these points *M*?

**UPDATE**

In this Geogebra [sketch](https://www.geogebra.org/m/yzq8tkjn) I show a 'proof' that point X(883) satisfies the condition
$$
S=\frac{xyz}{r}.
$$
so that its isotomic conjugate *[X(885)](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X883)* also satisfies the same condition. So the curve in question is passing through the Triangle Centers X(7),X(8), X(883),X(885) and probably some others as well.
The question still remains whether it is the *[Tucker-Gergonne-Nagel cubic](https://bernard-gibert.pagesperso-orange.fr/Exemples/k013.html)* or some other one.

Also the second question concerning the locus of points  for which the equation

$$
S=\frac{2xyz}{R}.
$$

is satisfied    remains unsolved as of yet. Only 1 triangle center that is always lying on this curve is known for certain.

Comment: Also please note that for the case where point M is the centroid the formula looks as follows: S = 2xyz/R, where R is the radius of the circumcircle. Substitution x=b/2, y=a/2, z=c/2 brings it back to the  classic S = abc/4R. Perhaps, some other triangle centers might exist, so that this equation S = 2xyz/R holds true for them as well...             I wonder in what particular relation these hypothetical points might be to the centroid of ABC?

Comment: Due to Ceva's theorem we have $xyz=AB_1\cdot BC_1\cdot C_1A=B_1C\cdot C_1A\cdot A_1B$ and for isotomic conjugate these products are the same.

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed non-equilateral triangle $ABC$, it appears to be the case that the locus of points $M$ for which the equation
$$
xyz=rS
$$
is satisfied is a simple closed curve in the interior of the given triangle.

[image]

As an example, for a triangle $ABC$ with $a=5,b=6,c=5$, the diagram above shows the triangle together with the locus of qualifying points $M$.

For the above example, using vertices
$$
A=(-3,0),\;\;\;B=(0,4),\;\;\;C=(3,0)
$$
the locus of qualifying points $M$ is the set of points $(x,y)$ with $1\le y \le {\large{\frac{12}{7}}}\;$such that the equation
$$
x^2
=
\frac
{
9(y-1)(4-y)(12-7y)
}
{
16(7y-3)
}
$$
is satisfied.

Comment: I wonder whether this https://bernard-gibert.pagesperso-orange.fr/Exemples/k013.html might be the one...  Fat chance. They look a bit different though.

Comment: 9 points determine a cubic and only 4 points have been identified so far. There is still a small chance that that it can be completely another one. "Tucker-Gergonne-Nagel cubic is the locus of point M such that the cevian triangles of X(7) and M have the same area."   This interpretation is a bit different from "the locus of points  for which the equation =* is satisfied".

Comment: @A Z: In this context, I'm not sure what would be meant by a "center".

Comment: @A Z: If there's a particular triangle for which you'd like to see the curve, let me know.

Comment: @A Z: If the triangle is equilateral, the only qualifying point $M$ is the centroid. For a non-equilateral triangle, it appears to be the case that the centroid is in the interior of the region bounded by the locus of qualifying points $M$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it's too long for comment.

Denote $c=AB$, $a=BC$, $c=AB$ and $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}=\frac{P_{ABC}}{2}$. It's well-known that if $M$ is the Gergonne point of the triangle $ABC$, then $AB_1=AC_1=p-a$, $BC_1=BA_1=p-b$, $CA_1=CB_1=p-c$ and $S=\frac{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}{r}$.

Now, suppose that point $M$ inside $\triangle ABC$ satisfy condition $S=\frac{xyz}{r}$. Then, we have the following system
$$
\begin{cases}
xyz=(p-a)(p-b)(p-c),
\\
xyz=(b-x)(c-y)(a-z),
\end{cases}
$$
where $(x,y,z)\in(0,b)\times(0,c)\times(0,a)$. (The second equation is the Ceva's theorem)

Moreover, it's easy to see that if $(x,y,z)$ satisfies this system, then corresponding cevians will be concurrent and $S=\frac{xyz}{r}$. Thus, we need to determine all solutions of the system above. We know already two of them: $(x,y,z)=(p-a,p-b,p-c)$ and $(x,y,z)=(p-c,p-a,p-b)$.

Probably, it would be better to rewrite this system as follows (here $u=p-a$, $v=p-b$, $w=p-c$; note that $a=(p-b)+(p-c)=v+w$ and similarly $b=w+u$ and $c=u+v$):
$$
\begin{cases}
xyz=uvw,
\\
xyz=(v+w-x)(w+u-y)(u+v-z),
\end{cases}
\text{where}~(x,y,z)\in (v+w,w+u,u+v).
$$
Exapnding the second equation (along with the first equation) gives
$$
\begin{cases}
xyz=uvw
\\
\sum\limits_{cyc}(w+u)(u+v)x-\sum\limits_{cyc}(v+w)yz=\sum\limits_{cyc}u^2(v+w)
\end{cases}
$$
Even for $u=v=w=1$ this system, I think, has infinitely many soltions
$$
\begin{cases}
xyz=1,
\\
2(x+y+z)-(xy+yz+zx)=3.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I just checked that the Triangle Center X(883) satisfies the condition =/,  so that X(885) must also satisfy the same condition and the cubic in question is inevitably                 
     Tucker-Gergonne-Nagel cubic:  https://bernard-gibert.pagesperso-orange.fr/Exemples/k013.html